# sudo apt-get install mysql-server fails

Tags: mysql, apt

I'm coming from a fresh install of Ubuntu server 9.10 and trying to install mysql-server by using 'sudo apt-get mysql-server'

I get the following errors:
    dan@dev:~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
    [sudo] password for dan:
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree
    Reading state information... Done
    The following extra packages will be installed:
    libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libhtml-template-perl
    libnet-daemon-perl libplrpc-perl mysql-client-5.1
    mysql-server-5.1
    Suggested packages:
    dbishell libipc-sharedcache-perl tinyca
    The following NEW packages will be installed:
    libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libhtml-template-perl
    libnet-daemon-perl libplrpc-perl mysql-client-5.1
    mysql-server mysql-server-5.1
    0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 
    Need to get 16.5MB of archives.
    After this operation, 39.0MB of additional disk space will be used.
    Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
    Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/main libnet-daemon-perl 0.43-1 [46.9kB]
    Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/main libplrpc-perl 0.2020-2 [36.0kB]
    Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/main libdbi-perl 1.609-1 [800kB]
    Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/main libdbd-mysql-perl 4.011-1ubuntu1 [136kB]
    Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/main mysql-client-5.1 5.1.37-  1ubuntu5.1 [8,202kB]
    Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/main mysql-server-5.1 5.1.37-1ubuntu5.1 [7,186kB]
    Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/main libhtml-template-perl 2.9-1 [65.8kB]
    Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/main mysql-server 5.1.37-1ubuntu5.1 [64.3kB]
    Fetched 16.5MB in 1min 34s (175kB/s)
    Preconfiguring packages ...
    Selecting previously deselected package libnet-daemon-perl.
    (Reading database ... 123083 files and directories currently installed.)
    Unpacking libnet-daemon-perl (from .../libnet-daemon-perl_0.43-1_all.deb) ...
    Selecting previously deselected package libplrpc-perl.
    Unpacking libplrpc-perl (from .../libplrpc-perl_0.2020-2_all.deb) ...
    Selecting previously deselected package libdbi-perl.
    Unpacking libdbi-perl (from .../libdbi-perl_1.609-1_i386.deb) ...
    Selecting previously deselected package libdbd-mysql-perl.
    Unpacking libdbd-mysql-perl (from .../libdbd-mysql-perl_4.011-1ubuntu1_i386.deb) ...
    Selecting previously deselected package mysql-client-5.1.
    Unpacking mysql-client-5.1 (from .../mysql-client-5.1_5.1.37-1ubuntu5.1_i386.deb) ...
    Selecting previously deselected package mysql-server-5.1.
    Unpacking mysql-server-5.1 (from .../mysql-server-5.1_5.1.37-1ubuntu5.1_i386.deb) ...
    Selecting previously deselected package libhtml-template-perl. 
    Unpacking libhtml-template-perl (from .../libhtml-template-perl_2.9-1_all.deb) ...
    Selecting previously deselected package mysql-server.
    Unpacking mysql-server (from .../mysql-server_5.1.37-1ubuntu5.1_all.deb) ...
    Processing triggers for man-db ...
    Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
    ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
    Setting up libnet-daemon-perl (0.43-1) ...
    Setting up libplrpc-perl (0.2020-2) ...
    Setting up libdbi-perl (1.609-1) ...
    Setting up libdbd-mysql-perl (4.011-1ubuntu1) ...
     Setting up mysql-client-5.1 (5.1.37-1ubuntu5.1) ...

```
Setting up mysql-server-5.1 (5.1.37-1ubuntu5.1) ...  
 * Stopping MySQL database server mysqld                [ OK ]   
 * Starting MySQL database server mysqld                [fail]   
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.           
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.1 (--configure):         
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1                                                   
Setting up libhtml-template-perl (2.9-1) ...                   
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:                                                              
mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.1; however:            
Package mysql-server-5.1 is not configured yet.              
dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):             
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured                    
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                       Errors were encountered while processing:
mysql-server-5.1
mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What am I missing?

[update]
mysqld returns:

```
dan@dev:~$ sudo mysqld                                                                           
[sudo] password for dan:                                                                         
100220 12:18:17 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.                                           
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11                                                      
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process                                
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.                                                 
100220 12:18:17  InnoDB: Retrying to lock the first data file                                    
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11                                                      
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
```

This goes on for a while...

```
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
^[[BInnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
100220 12:19:57  InnoDB: Unable to open the first data file
InnoDB: Error in opening ./ibdata1
100220 12:19:57  InnoDB: Operating system error number 11 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Error number 11 means 'Resource temporarily unavailable'.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
InnoDB: Could not open or create data files.
InnoDB: If you tried to add new data files, and it failed here,
InnoDB: you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back
InnoDB: to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created
InnoDB: in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of
InnoDB: zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not
InnoDB: remove old data files which contain your precious data!
100220 12:19:57 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
100220 12:19:57 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
100220 12:19:57 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Address already in use
100220 12:19:57 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
100220 12:19:57 [ERROR] Aborting

100220 12:19:57 [Warning] Forcing shutdown of 1 plugins
100220 12:19:57 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

How can I check what process is using port: 3306?

[Update]:
`sudo netstat -anp | grep LISTEN`
returns

```
dan@dev:~$ sudo netstat -anp | grep LISTEN                                                              
[sudo] password for dan:                                                                                
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1372/master     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4391/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1409/cupsd      
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      1409/cupsd
```

[More Updates]:
I can log into mysql if that makes a difference

Answer (score 1):

In this case, here's what I would try:

Try to reinstall mysql-server-5.1:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall mysql-server-5.1
```

Try to reinstall mysql-server:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall mysql-server
```

Try to reconfigure mysql-server-5.1 and try reinstall again:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.1
sudo apt-get install --reinstall mysql-server
```

Answer (score 1):

The `mysql-server-5.1` package tries to start MySQL after the package is installed, which fails. The first thing you need to do is finish the installation process cleanly. There are several ways to do this:

- either fix your MySQL configuration, check that `/etc/init.d/mysql-server` works, and launch `dpkg --configure -a` to finish the installation process ;
- or edit `/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.1.postinst` and remove the part where it starts the server (probably calling `/etc/init.d/mysql-server start` or so), then launch `dpkg --configure -a` to finish the installation process and then fix your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try `lsof -i @localhost:3306`.  You may need to install lsof, but it is a fantastic tool to have at your disposal.

Comment: Or:

sudo netstat -tlnp

Comment: @Mircea, this deserves to be a separate answer.  One advantage of lsof is that it will show all applications accessing the specified port - though perhaps not needed here.